# How to share a link with image and description in facebook iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdksharekit

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"attachment_blank.png"];
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImage:image userGenerated:NO];
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                               @"og:type": @"app:recipe",
                               @"og:title": @"Sample Recipe",
                               @"og:description": @"",
                               @"og:url": @"http://samples.ogp.me/216213502062059",
                               @"og:image": @[photo]
                           };
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];
FBSDKShareAPI *shareAPI = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc] init];
[shareAPI createOpenGraphObject:object];
```

The submission guidelines speak about a "user generated photos" permission that doesn't seem to be available anywhere in the app settings, or anywhere else in the documentation. Is that still required? Is there a similar permission for images?

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this method to share an image with link. The image you want to share should need to be on server(i.e. you need to use link of an image )
Note:- You must have an "publish_actions" permission from facebook app*

Below method is shown using the facebook sdk 4.3

*In .h file*

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBRequestConnection *requestConnection;
```

*In .m file*

```
-(IBAction)facebookBtn:(id)sender{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_events", @"user_location", @"publish_actions"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState state,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                if (error)
                                {
                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                                          if (error.code!=2)
                                          {
                                              [alertView show];
                                          }

                                      }
                                      else if (session.isOpen)
                                      {

                                          [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                              [self requestCompleted:connection forFbID:@"me" result:result error:error];
                                          }];
                                                                                       // create the connection object
                                          FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

                                          // create a handler block to handle the results of the request for fbid's profile
                                          FBRequestHandler handler =
                                          ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                              // output the results of the request
                                              [self requestCompleted:connection forFbID:@"me" result:result error:error];
                                              [self showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"Posted successfully", nil)];
                                          };

                                          // create the request object, using the fbid as the graph path
                                          // as an alternative the request* static methods of the FBRequest class could
                                          // be used to fetch common requests, such as /me and /me/friends
                                          NSString *messageString=[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Just parked at %@ with #ParkHero", nil),@"miami"];
                                          NSString *imageUrl = @"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFoE4FjiykSb-3usYJ6OuyUsa_NB0s0B13u52IKK80se0qOwPJ" ;
                                          // Your facebook application link
                                          NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"https://www.facebook.com/ParkHero?fref=ts", @"link",imageUrl, @"picture",messageString,@"message",nil];



                                          FBRequest *request=[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];


                                          [newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];

                                          // if there's an outstanding connection, just cancel
                                          [self.requestConnection cancel];

                                          // keep track of our connection, and start it
                                          self.requestConnection = newConnection;
                                          [newConnection start];
                                      }
                }];
}
else
{
    FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    // create a handler block to handle the results of the request for fbid's profile
    FBRequestHandler handler = ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        // output the results of the request
        [self requestCompleted:connection forFbID:@"me" result:result error:error];
        [self showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"Posted successfully", nil)];
    };

    // create the request object, using the fbid as the graph path
    // as an alternative the request* static methods of the FBRequest class could
    // be used to fetch common requests, such as /me and /me/friends
    NSString *messageString=[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Just parked at %@ with #ParkHero", nil),@"miami"];
    NSString *imageUrl = @"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFoE4FjiykSb-3usYJ6OuyUsa_NB0s0B13u52IKK80se0qOwPJ";
// Your facebook application link
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"https://www.facebook.com/ParkHero?fref=ts", @"link",imageUrl, @"picture",messageString,@"message",nil];

    FBRequest *request=[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];

    // if there's an outstanding connection, just cancel
    [self.requestConnection cancel];

    // keep track of our connection, and start it
    self.requestConnection = newConnection;
    [newConnection start];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,Is there anyway to share image without imageUrl